# jQuery validation not updating error message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, apache, validation

I have a form that asks the user for an address, on this form there's a postal code field. This field is remotely checked against a Canadian postal code RegEX for validity.

If the data in the field doesn't pass the test, an error message is displayed showing what is typed in the field + "is not a valid postal code".

i.e. if I type "44444" and try to validate, the error says "44444 is not a valid postal code".

The PHP scripted has been tested and works, the remote check through the jQuery validation script works, it returns true or false correctly, but if you play around with the postal code to test it, and change it enough times, the error message stops updating so what you get is, instead of "44444 is not a valid postal code", it will say something like "44 is not a valid postal code", it always seems to be an older combination that you tried within the same "page load".

When this happens, the script will still work, if you type a correct postal code in it will pass and the error message disappears.

Typing in an incorrect one will fail and show the error message again, but that error message doesn't show the new data you typed in, it shows you something you typed in earlier, i.e. if you type "L3B 555", instead of showing "L3B 555 is not a valid postal code" it will say "44 is not a valid postal code" and stay stuck on an earlier input until you refresh the page and start over.

Again, even once this starts happening, the script will still pass a valid postal code and allow you through the form.

This is my first shot at validation this complicated so forgive me if it's something obvious.

Here is the javascript:

```
var validator = $("#newReviewForm").validate({

            onkeyup: false,         
            rules: {
                //Here we name each field from the page that we are validating
                streetNo: {
                    required: true,
                },
                streetName : {
                    required: true,
                },
                town: {
                    required: true,
                },
                postal: {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "_libraries/PHP/newReview_postalRegex.php",
                        type: "post",

                    },
                },
                province: {
                    required: true,
                },
            },
            messages: {
                //Here we place the messages we want displayed when a form is invalid
                streetNo: {
                    required: "We need the unit number.",
                },
                streetName : {
                    required: "We need the street's name."
                },
                town: {
                    required: "We need the town's name."
                },
                postal: {
                    required: "Please enter a postal code.",
                    remote: $.validator.format("{0} is not a valid postal code."),

                },
                province: {
                    required: "Please enter a valid Province",
                    required: true,
                },
            },
            errorLabelContainer: "#errorMessages",
            wrapper: "li",
            submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!")},



        });
```

The remote PHP code:

```
  <?php
       $request = trim(strtoupper($_REQUEST['postal']));
       $postal = $request;
       $valid = 'true';

       $regex = '^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$^';

       if (preg_match($regex, $postal)) {
           echo $valid;
       } else {
           $valid = 'false';
           echo $valid;
       }
   ?>
```

And the form:

```
<form id="newReviewForm" method="post" action="#">
        <table>             
              <tr>
                <td class="title">Street Number</td>
                <td>                  
                    <input type="text" name="streetNo" id="streetNo" required="required"/></td><td class="status"></td>

                <td class="title" style="float: right">Apt #</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="aptNo" id="aptNo" /></td><td class="status"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>      
                <td class="title">Street Name</td>
                <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="streetName" id="streetName" /></td><td class="status"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="title">Town</td>
                <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="town" id="town" /></td><td class="status"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="title">Postal Code</td>
                <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="postal" id="postal" /></td><td class="status"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="title">Province</td>
                <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="province" id="province" /></td><td class="status"></td>
              </tr>             
      </table>  
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="errorMessages"></div>
```

I don't think it's a PHP issue but I'm at a loss right now and can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Check the PHP is functioning correctly first by manually calling `_libraries/PHP/newReview_postalRegex.php?postal=L3B 555`

Comment: Yes the PHP works, I did try that to make sure. Like I was saying, the script itself will check for validation and pass or fail the input correctly, it's just that error message displayed after a while stops updating in the DOM it seems.

Comment: Don't you need a success function for validate? `success: function(data){if(data == 'true'){return true;}}`

Comment: Yes I do, I have one elsewhere in the code, it works. I didn't include it here because all of that is working. It is simply the error message displayed stops showing the "latest" input typed by the user after a while.

Comment: Oh try to remove the alert, I'm not sure but this can foul up some js operations until it's cleared.

Comment: Gave it a shot, didn't work. Also tried adding "cache: false," to the remote options and that didn't work either. It seems like if I try the changes quickly, it hangs up, but if I try a bunch of things slowly, it stays functional for a lot longer until it hangs up. Maybe this is a server issue?